# Incompatibility between etoc and mwbk

Tags: etoc, mwcls

When I use the `etoc` package with the `mwbk` class, `\localtableofcontents` works (with errors), but `\tableofcontents` does not:

```
\documentclass{mwbk}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoc}

%doesn't work%%
%\etocstandardlines% ‘line entries’ as without \usepackage{etoc}
%\etocstandarddisplaystyle  % ‘toc display’ as without \usepackage{etoc}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\etocsettocstyle{\section*{In this chapter you will see:}}{} % from now on only local tocs


\chapter{Chapter One}

\localtableofcontents


\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One Point One}
\section{Section Two}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tocloft` package for compatibility.

```
\documentclass{mwbk}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}

%doesn't work%%
%\etocstandardlines% ‘line entries’ as without \usepackage{etoc}
%\etocstandarddisplaystyle  % ‘toc display’ as without \usepackage{etoc}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\etocsettocstyle{\section*{In this chapter you will see:}}{} % from now on only local tocs


\chapter{Chapter One}

\localtableofcontents


\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One Point One}
\section{Section Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works well, although the `tocloft` package changes a little bit of the `toc` formatting.